# Refining repeating selectors on Cypress

Tags: css-selectors, cypress

Hi i'm doing a code clean up in my project and i just want to clarify it this 2 codes is providing the same behavior? I just want to try shorter methods and avoid repeating of selectors

```
it('Check all logos if visible', () => {
        cy.get('[class="images"] img:nthchild(1)').should('be.visible')
        cy.get('[class="images"] img:nth-child(2)').should('be.visible')
        cy.get('[class="images"] img:nth-child(3)').should('be.visible')
```

```
it('Check all logos if visible', () => {
        cy.get('[class="images"] img').each(($el) => {
            expect($el).to.be.visible
          })
```

Comment: Yes as far as I can see, there's no circumstance where 1st passes and 2nd fails, or vice versa. Also ``[class="images"]`` can be ``.images``. If you want you can also `cy.wrap($el).should('be.visible')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One difference is `cy.get('[class="images"] img').each()` will not provide regression coverage if one of the `img` doesn't load for some reason (e.g resource missing from the server).

Try

```js
cy.get('[class="images"] img')
  .should('have.length', 3)
  .each(($el) => {
    expect($el).to.be.visible
  })
```

Comment: Yeah this is what i thought too. Need to check the length first if i have the the same number of img displaying